# working with null and bit fields with php and sql server

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, parameters

I am going to be using the value of this:

```
$HEA_LivingWill  = $_POST['HEA_LivingWill'] == 'on'  ? true : false;
```

to update a `bit` field in a sql server table.

please notice the code above is php.

i suppose the value of `$_POST['HEA_LivingWill']` can be `'on'`, `null`, or what ever is the opposite of 'on'

**What is the correct way to handle a `bit` sql server field from a regular variable in php?**

please note that when i do a sql statment like `update mytable set my field =$HEA_LivingWill` the query doesn't even go through. it doesnt give me an error message, and i know the query is not execute because i checked with sql server profiler/

please note that i've also tried to do `$HEA_LivingWill  = $_POST['HEA_LivingWill'] == 'on'  ? 1:0;` receiving the same results.

if it's interesting to you, here's the insert statement that is run from php:

```
 $create_info = mssql_query("INSERT INTO 
 Health 
 (RES_ID, HEA_LastUser, HEA_DateStamp, HEA_Vision, HEA_Hearing, HEA_Mobility, HEA_Falls, HEA_Food, HEA_FoodPref, HEA_FoodDetails, HEA_Insect, HEA_InsectDetails, HEA_Driver, HEA_Make, HEA_Model, HEA_Year, HEA_Color, HEA_Plate, HEA_ParkArea, HEA_Care, HEA_Height, HEA_Weight, HEA_History1, HEA_History2, HEA_History3, HEA_History4, HEA_History5, HEA_History6, HEA_History7, HEA_History8, HEA_History9, HEA_History10, HEA_History11, HEA_History12, HEA_History13, HEA_History14, HEA_History15, HEA_History16, HEA_OtherIll, HEA_HistoryDetails, HEA_HospName, HEA_HospPhone, HEA_PhyName1, HEA_PhyAddress1, HEA_PhyPhone1, HEA_PhyFax1, HEA_PhyEmail1, HEA_PhySpecialty1, HEA_PhyName2, HEA_PhyAddress2, HEA_PhyPhone2, HEA_PhyFax2, HEA_PhyEmail2, HEA_PhySpecialty2, HEA_OtherAll, HEA_OtherDetails, HEA_Pendant, HEA_Storage

 ,HEA_LivingWill            
  ,HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney
  ,HEA_POLST                 
  ,HEA_MOST                  
  ,HEA_DNR     )              

 VALUES 
 ('$RES_ID', '$USR_ID', '$HEA_DateStamp','$HEA_Vision', '$HEA_Hearing', '$HEA_Mobility', '$HEA_Falls', '$HEA_Food', '$HEA_FoodPref', '$HEA_FoodDetails', '$HEA_Insect', '$HEA_InsectDetails', '$HEA_Driver', '$HEA_Make', '$HEA_Model', '$HEA_Year', '$HEA_Color', '$HEA_Plate', '$HEA_ParkArea', '$HEA_Care', '$HEA_Height', '$HEA_Weight', '$HEA_History1', '$HEA_History2', '$HEA_History3', '$HEA_History4', '$HEA_History5', '$HEA_History6', '$HEA_History7', '$HEA_History8', '$HEA_History9', '$HEA_History10', '$HEA_History11', '$HEA_History12', '$HEA_History13', '$HEA_History14', '$HEA_History15', '$HEA_History16', '$HEA_OtherIll', '$HEA_HistoryDetails', '$HEA_HospName', '$HEA_HospPhone', '$HEA_PhyName1', '$HEA_PhyAddress1', '$HEA_PhyPhone1', '$HEA_PhyFax1', '$HEA_PhyEmail1', '$HEA_PhySpecialty1', '$HEA_PhyName2', '$HEA_PhyAddress2', '$HEA_PhyPhone2', '$HEA_PhyFax2', '$HEA_PhyEmail2', '$HEA_PhySpecialty2', '$HEA_OtherAll', '$HEA_OtherDetails', '$HEA_Pendant', '$HEA_Storage' 

 ,'$HEA_LivingWill'          //please also note i have tried without the single quotes for these 5 variables
 ,'$HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney'
 ,'$HEA_POLST'                 
 ,'$HEA_MOST'                  
 ,'$HEA_DNR'                
 )") or die ("Error - No record creation");
```

i'm certain that i'm missing some details, please let me know what else i can provide.

here's the structure for the `HEALTH` table:

```
USE [KCustom]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Health]    Script Date: 6/19/2013 10:17:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Health](
    [HEA_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RES_ID] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_LastUser] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_DateStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [HEA_Vision] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_Hearing] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_Mobility] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_Falls] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_Food] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_FoodPref] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_FoodDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_Insect] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_InsectDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_Driver] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_Make] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Model] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Year] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Plate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_ParkArea] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Care] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_Height] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Weight] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_History1] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History2] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History3] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History4] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History5] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History6] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History7] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History8] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History9] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History10] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History11] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History12] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History13] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History14] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History15] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_History16] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_OtherIll] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [HEA_HistoryDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_HospName] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [HEA_HospPhone] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [HEA_HospAddress] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyName1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyAddress1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyPhone1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyFax1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyEmail1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhySpecialty1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyName2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyAddress2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyPhone2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyFax2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhyEmail2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PhySpecialty2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_OtherAll] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [HEA_OtherDetails] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_RespParty] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_MovedFrom] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespAddress] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespPhone] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespEmail] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespGuardian] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespPOA] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_PersonRespPayee] [int] NULL,
    [HEA_DentistName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_DentistAddr] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_DentistPhone] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_DentistEmail] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_CaseName] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_CaseAddr] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_CasePhone] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_CaseEmail] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HEA_Pendant] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_Storage] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [HEA_LivingWill] [bit] NULL,
    [HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney] [bit] NULL,
    [HEA_POLST] [bit] NULL,
    [HEA_MOST] [bit] NULL,
    [HEA_DNR] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Health] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HEA_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

please note the `$_POST[] variables` are being grabbed from the previous page. here the source of the [entire first page](http://pastebin.com/TvXKCaBX) from where these variables originate.

if you would like to see the entire source code of the page that does the `INSERT`[, here it is.](http://pastebin.com/ndZEaDWR)

I did put:

```
or var_dump($create_info);
```

instead of `or die(...);`

and although nothing errored out, nothing was executed either

i've also tried to place

```
,1,1,1,1,1            
 )") or die ("Error - No record creation");
```

instead of:

```
 ,$HEA_LivingWill          
 ,$HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney
 ,$HEA_POLST 
 ,$HEA_MOST                  
 ,$HEA_DNR  )") or die ("Error - No record creation");
```

and there was no change in the result. the record was not affected

Comment: `$HEA_LivingWill  = $_POST['HEA_LivingWill'] = 'on'  ? true : false;` shouldn't you use `== 'on'`?

Comment: thats a good point, however, still getting the same result

Comment: Your "update statement" is actually an insert statement. So again, are you trying to update or insert?

Comment: apologies i meant INSERT

Comment: Please post your database structure for `Health`. Also I counted 63 column names and they matched up.

Comment: @DaveChen ive posted it thakn u

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` Are there any errors?

Comment: no, there are no errors, it goes through without problems. however the INSERT doenst even get executed

Comment: @budwiser ive tried both!

Comment: Did you try removing single quotes from the variables containing bit values?

Comment: @budwiser do you mean 1 instead of '1' ? i posted the entire code that populates those variables in the first place

Comment: @DaveChen http://pastebin.com/TvXKCaBX  this will show you the code that populates those variables in the first place

Comment: @Артём Царионов, Yes, like in the insert-statement `$HEA_LivingWill` instead of `'$HEA_LivingWill'`?

Comment: yes, indeed i have tried to do that without the quotes in the insert statement

Comment: ive also posted the source code of the entire site that has the insert query

Comment: @DaveChen so what do u think? shall i go through the php logs?

Comment: @budwiser would u have anymore suggestions?

Comment: 500 points to thee answer!!!

Comment: please note that ive included complete source. at this point it's probably a bug in the system. funny how can that be since it's 5.3 very old version of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the insert with this:

```
$create_info = mssql_query("INSERT INTO 
Health 
(RES_ID, HEA_LastUser, HEA_DateStamp, HEA_Vision, HEA_Hearing, HEA_Mobility, HEA_Falls, HEA_Food, HEA_FoodPref, HEA_FoodDetails, HEA_Insect, HEA_InsectDetails, HEA_Driver, HEA_Make, HEA_Model, HEA_Year, HEA_Color, HEA_Plate, HEA_ParkArea, HEA_Care, HEA_Height, HEA_Weight, HEA_History1, HEA_History2, HEA_History3, HEA_History4, HEA_History5, HEA_History6, HEA_History7, HEA_History8, HEA_History9, HEA_History10, HEA_History11, HEA_History12, HEA_History13, HEA_History14, HEA_History15, HEA_History16, HEA_OtherIll, HEA_HistoryDetails, HEA_HospName, HEA_HospPhone, HEA_PhyName1, HEA_PhyAddress1, HEA_PhyPhone1, HEA_PhyFax1, HEA_PhyEmail1, HEA_PhySpecialty1, HEA_PhyName2, HEA_PhyAddress2, HEA_PhyPhone2, HEA_PhyFax2, HEA_PhyEmail2, HEA_PhySpecialty2, HEA_OtherAll, HEA_OtherDetails, HEA_Pendant, HEA_Storage

,HEA_LivingWill            
,HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney
,HEA_POLST                 
,HEA_MOST                  
,HEA_DNR     )              

VALUES 
($RES_ID, $USR_ID, '$HEA_DateStamp',$HEA_Vision, $HEA_Hearing, $HEA_Mobility, $HEA_Falls, '$HEA_Food', $HEA_FoodPref, '$HEA_FoodDetails', '$HEA_Insect', '$HEA_InsectDetails', '$HEA_Driver', '$HEA_Make', '$HEA_Model', '$HEA_Year', '$HEA_Color', '$HEA_Plate', '$HEA_ParkArea', $HEA_Care, '$HEA_Height', '$HEA_Weight', '$HEA_History1', '$HEA_History2', '$HEA_History3', '$HEA_History4', '$HEA_History5', '$HEA_History6', '$HEA_History7', '$HEA_History8', '$HEA_History9', '$HEA_History10', '$HEA_History11', '$HEA_History12', '$HEA_History13', '$HEA_History14', '$HEA_History15', '$HEA_History16', '$HEA_OtherIll', '$HEA_HistoryDetails', '$HEA_HospName', '$HEA_HospPhone', '$HEA_PhyName1', '$HEA_PhyAddress1', '$HEA_PhyPhone1', '$HEA_PhyFax1', '$HEA_PhyEmail1', '$HEA_PhySpecialty1', '$HEA_PhyName2', '$HEA_PhyAddress2', '$HEA_PhyPhone2', '$HEA_PhyFax2', '$HEA_PhyEmail2', '$HEA_PhySpecialty2', '$HEA_OtherAll', '$HEA_OtherDetails', '$HEA_Pendant', '$HEA_Storage' 

,$HEA_LivingWill          
,$HEA_Medical_Power_Attorney
,$HEA_POLST                 
,$HEA_MOST                  
,$HEA_DNR                
)") or die ("Error - No record creation");
```

If it still doesn't work, please do a `var_dump($create_info)` after the query.

Comment: @Артём Царионов, did you try this?

Comment: thanks so much, what is it that you changed? i will try right now

Comment: for this statement i got Error - No record creation

Comment: At least that should prove that your original query executes although not as expected... If you run the original query and do the `var_dump($create_info)`, what's in it?

Comment: i did that query like this........... ,$HEA_MOST                  
,$HEA_DNR                
)") or var_dump($create_info);    (as you can see at the end i put var_dump instead of "or die" and the dump didnt show anything, is it supposed to?

Comment: Try with the original query and don't replace the `or die()` with var_dump, just place it below it instead.

Comment: whats that supposed to do? i just placed it below and same result

Comment: May I ask one more thing... try my query above once more, but this time replace `or die()` with `or die('Error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());` Tell me what it says.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32093/discussion-between-budwiser-and--)

Answer (score -1):

```
$HEA_LivingWill  = ($_POST['HEA_LivingWill'] =='on')  ? 1 : 0;
```

You'll need to convert the False/True value to 0/1. SQL Server won't do this implicit conversion for you.

Comment: remove singlecolons around the  '$HEA_LivingWill' in insert statement

Comment: According to the post, he has tried `$HEA_LivingWill = $_POST['HEA_LivingWill']` **=** `'on' ? 1:0;` which is different.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TvXKCaBX   this code shows the variables being populated in the first place

Comment: ive also posted the source code of the entire site that has the insert query

Comment: @DynamicDeveloper so what do you think? any other suggestions?